# Mobile App with Contact of Salesforce as an User

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Scenario: I am trying to build a Mobile APP, the Contacts of salesforce.com would be the user of that Mobile APP.

Suppose I am a contact in salesforce, and when I logged in Mobile APP, I need to see all my cases present in salesforce.

Is it possible ? If so How to design

Please help.

Comment: Is it possible without Community?

Comment: No, you must use Community or some kind of user. If you don't, then your client is in violation of the salesforce.com Terms of Service, and the entire org can be deactivated. Trying to get around Salesforce security features is a bad idea and no consultant should take those kinds of projects, as they are, technically, illegal as you are a party to a violation of a contract between the client and salesforce.com.

Answer (score 3):

> 1)Lets first choose appropriate license for your business problem

The two awesome posts that can help you regarding this are as follows

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html

You will need to make a choice between **Customer Community and Customer Community Plus**

> 2)Our next step will be how to Provision Users for this community license

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/06/how-to-provision-salesforce-communities-users.html

You will need to decide this based on you are going with Visualforce or Local Approach with HTML pages .(API will be best choice ).

Depending on Volume you will need to decide whether you need JIT (Just In Time Provisioning or not)

> 3)Establish Oauth for connecting Mobile Device and Salesforce community

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html

The above will be your best guide in figuring out the solution for your problem

> 4)Naive App or Hybrid (Local using Javascript Framework,ForceTK or Server Side Hybrid with VF,Apex and Javascript)

https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/services/mobile-packs

Explore Mobile Packs if you prefer Hybrid solution

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the reply, One Question Is it possible without community? My Client has salesforce and they do want to go and buy Community. So wanted to check , is there any other way to have a solution without buying community.

Comment: No if you want your contact as Users community Licence is needed .Other way would be to use Heruko for hosting users but again Heruko will also cost .You may need to compare this as well